# I want to change url by htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

i want to change url by htaccess from `http://localhost/projectname/cab-details.php?v_name=variable` to `http://localhost/projectname/variable` Here **variable is a link(slug)** Now My htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^$1/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+) cab-details.php?v_name=$1
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^$1/([a-zA-Z-0-9-]+)` makes little sense; `$1` is a back reference to the first capture group of the _current_ pattern.

Comment: that is possible or not sir..

Comment: The condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` for the URL `/test` is literally "if a file called test.php **does not** exist", and it doesn't make sense to route the request to such a file then

Comment: Also, if you are more comfortable in PHP than htaccess, maybe consider using a single router script with [FallbackResource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/231316)

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /omm/
##External redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(omm/[^.]*)\.php\?v_name=(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal redirect rules here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^omm/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$  $1.php?v_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: my php page click link code is `<a href="cab-details.php?v_name=varable" class="col vi-details">View Details</a>`  Please help me here changes..

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, Could you please do let me know what sample link you have hit and what's happening once you hit it? Thank you

Comment: After sample link click change page and here link `http://localhost/omm/cab-details` here not get variable also error occurs `Warning: Undefined array key "v_name" in D:\xamp\htdocs\omm\cab-details.php on line 5`. Please help me in link changes

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, Sorry to say but this is NOT clear. Please tell these things: **1st:** What link you are hitting? **2nd:** What is happening after hitting that link? **3rd:** what is happening to link after using my htaccess code. Let me know on these details in detailed so that I can help you, cheers.

Comment: **1st** hitting link `<a href="<?php echo ($db->createSlug($row['v_name'], $delimiter = '-'));  ?>` in a tag pass only vehicle link (ac-swift-dzire). **2nd** After hitting i want to redirect `cab-details.php` with variable **v_name** like in php `cab-details.php?v_name=varable` (variable like - ac-swift-dzire). **3rd** After redirecting with variable i want to my link `http://localhost/omm/ac-swift-dzire` . Here **omm** is the project name and **ac-swift-dzire** is variable. Please help me

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, Ok I hope you have put my htaccess rules in your file. Now please do let me know when you hit `http://localhost/omm/ac-swift-dzire` link what happens in browser OR in backend? NOT from code side from htaccess side please.

Comment: I have changed the htaccess code only project name **omm**.  Like `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(omm/[^.]*)\.php\?v_name=(\S+)\s [NC]` and `RewriteRule ^(omm)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/cab-details.php?v_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]` . After done this hitting link then show in browser **Not Found** or **The requested URL was not found on this server.** . In Browser console **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** After hitting link then link is **http://localhost/omm/ac-swift-dzire** Actually i want to this link.

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, Ok now you have given some information which can lead us to FIX. So you are getting 404 error. 2 questions here: **1st:** where is your .htaccess located? Mention full path here. **2nd:** where is your php file(s) present mention their fill path also here. Let me know cheers.

Comment: **1st** me .htaccess file in root folder (omm - this my project folder - http://localhost/omm/).  **2nd** hitting link php file (index.php) also root folder (omm - this my project folder - http://localhost/omm/). **3rd** redirect to php (cab-details.php) also o root folder (omm - this my project folder - http://localhost/omm/).

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, Ok could you please change last line `RewriteRule ^(projectname)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/cab-details.php?v_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]` **To** `RewriteRule ^(projectname)/([^/]*)/?$  cab-details.php?v_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]` once and save your .htaccess file and clear your browser cache and try again. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: After `RewriteRule ^(projectname)/([^/]*)/?$  cab-details.php?v_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]` replace also change project name like `RewriteRule ^(omm)/([^/]*)/?$  cab-details.php?v_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]` then save and clear cache in browser. Same problem show in browser.  Not Found or The requested URL was not found on this server. . In Browser console Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) .

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, I think we both are not in sync. Let me clarify what I know about your question here. 1st: You are hitting link `http://localhost:80/projectname/test_singh.php` which should redirect to `http://localhost:80/test_singh` **then** it should internally rewrite(or being served by) file cab-details.php? This is what my understanding as of now, please do confirm me if I am right here? Thank you.

Comment: I want to change my link after hitting a link. In PHP `<a href="cab-details.php?v_link=<?php  echo($row['v_link'])?>">View Details</a>`. This My hitting link with variable (v_link). This hitting link PHP file (index.php) And link redirect PHP file (cab-details.php) Same Folder also .htaccess file same folder in my project. All Three files are root folder of my project (omm). omm is my project folder. After click link redirect to cab-details.php with variable like (http://localhost/omm/cab-details.php?v_link=ac-swift-dzire) here (ac-swift-dzire is v_link - variable). This is PHP is good working

Comment: But I want to change Here link after clicking link like (http://localhost/omm/variable-)**http://localhost/omm/ac-swift-dzire/** Here **omm** is project name ** ac-swift-dzire** valiable(v_link). please help me.

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, I am sorry its not clear, could you please mention url in code tags Eg: `http://localhost:80/test` use backticks to get comment values in code tags.

Comment: After hitting the link redirect to another page then link is `http://localhost/omm/cab-details.php?v_name=ac-swift-dzire`  in PHP. I want to change this link `http://localhost/omm/ac-swift-dzire` . Please help me.

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, I have updated my rules now, please do check once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: After Update .htaccess code and clear browser cache. Then run-in browser i got url `http://localhost/omm/cab-details/ac-swift-dzire` and `The requested URL was not found on this server.` . In browser console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` .

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, Ok change last line from `RewriteRule ^(omm)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/cab-details.php?v_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]` **to** `RewriteRule ^(omm)/([^/]*)/?$  /$1/cab-details.php?v_name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]` once and let me know how it goes.

Comment: After Update .htaccess code and clear browser cache. Then run-in browser i got url `http://localhost/omm/cab-details/ac-honda-amaze`  In browser show `The requested URL was not found on this server.` In browser console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, ok let's try one more thing. Add line `RewriteBase /omn/` after 1st of this shown .htaccess file. Let me know how it goes, fingers 

Comment: update `RewriteBase /omm/` . Then Same Problem

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, could you please once let me know complete path of htaccess omm and your php file. Like this: `/root/singh/test/.htaccess` etc

Comment: This is my xamp server location of .htaccess `D:\xamp\htdocs\omm` In Vs Code Editor path `D:\xamp\htdocs\omm\.htaccess`

Comment: All PHP file also here

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, I feel we are very close path is the only issue I could see. Is hraccess path is `D:\xamp\htdocs\.htaccess`?

Comment: .htaccess path of my project `D:\xamp\htdocs\omm\.htaccess` . Here **omm** is my project name

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, Ok please give a shot to my updated htaccess rules and let me know how it goes? Cheers.

Comment: Same Error `http://localhost/omm/cab-details/ac-honda-amaze` In browser show `The requested URL was not found on this server` . In browser console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, are you not hitting `http://localhost/projectname/cab-details.php?v_name=variable` like this link in browser? If not then these rules wouldn't work as I already stated in previous comments. These rules look for links like(example) `http://localhost/projectname/cab-details.php?v_name=variable` only.

Comment: Yes, I hitting `http://localhost/omm/cab-details.php?v_name=ac-swift-dzire` . I see at time hitting button mouse hover link has shown in browser bottom.

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, So means URL `http://localhost/omm/cab-details.php?v_name=ac-swift-dzire`  is going successfully redirect to url `http://localhost/omm/cab-details/ac-swift-dzire` but its giving 404 error. Ok 1 more thing your .htaccess and cab-details.php both are present inside omm folder right like this: `D:\xamp\htdocs\omm\.htaccess` **and** `D:\xamp\htdocs\omm\cab-details.php` correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right...

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, ok then my next check would be, can you check if you have %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} variable value set to `D:\xamp\htdocs` in your apache conf file? Because if its not set then it will cause issues. Let me know.

Comment: In apache conf  `ServerRoot "D:/xamp/apache"` . Are you exactly discus about this.

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, you mean %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} is set to `D:\xamp\htdocs` in conf file, sorry I didn't get your last comment.

Comment: @SrikantaSethy, Could you please do let me know if you have checked %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} and how it went?